# Why is my image not scaled correctly when hovered?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for a side project and I need to have 2 cards, presenting someone with an image on the left and some text + another image on the right.
I want that card to be 1.1 times scaled when hovered or focused but when I do the usual method (as in the snippet), somehow the image on the right shifts a bit to the top.

```css
/* GÉNÉRAL */

:root {
  --color-accent: #4e6eff;
  --color-accent-dark: #3a56d3;
  --color-black: #252728;
  --color-white: #fdfdff;
  --color-blacker: #0c0d0d;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 0;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::selection {
  background-color: #4e6effba;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-black);
  color: var(--color-white);
}


/*  COMMON STYLE */

.bg-accent {
  background-color: var(--color-accent);
  color: var(--color-white);
}

a {
  color: var(--color-white);
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*  */

.select-membres__row--2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.membre-carte {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: var(--color-blacker);
  text-align: center;
  scale: 1;
  transition: scale 100ms ease-out;
}

.membre-carte:hover {
  scale: 1.1;
  transition: scale 150ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.47, 0.35, 0.92);
  border: 3px solid var(--color-accent);
}

.membre-carte>* {
  width: 50%;
}

.membre-carte .carte-pp {
  border-radius: calc(25px - 0.5em);
}

.perso-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.carte__nom {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.perso-cont .img-cont {
  width: 120px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-membres__row--2">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="membre-carte">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/50x50" class="carte-pp">
      <div class="perso-cont">
        <h4 class="carte__nom">image 1</h4>
        <p class="carte__surnom">lorem</p>
        <div class="img-cont">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/40x40">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="membre-carte">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/50x50" class="carte-pp">
      <div class="perso-cont">
        <div>
          <h4 class="carte__nom">image 2</h4>
          <p class="carte__surnom">lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/40x40">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border in `.membre-carte:hover` consumes an extra `6px` (top `3px` and bottom `3px`) from the total height of the cart leaving less room for the content to fit in.

Add a transparent border like `.membre-carte { border: 3px solid transparent }` to you CSS and the movement will disappear, because now both the unhovered vs. hovered state consume the same amount of space again.

Be aware that you will lose `6px` of the carts spaces for their content to fit in.

Comment: Thx, this perfectly fixes the issue ! 
I just noticed that replacing the `.membre-carte:hover` border to a `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--color-accent)` also fixes the problem.